# Password matching validation using the Joi schema in React not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

I want to create a password change form in React. Here is the code of my component :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import "./Login/Login.css";
import { UAA } from "../../Actions/Types";

class ChangePassword extends Component {
  state = {
    account: {
      currentPassword: "",
      newPassword: "",
      newPasswordRepeated: "",
    },
    errors: {},
    auth: UAA,
  };

  schema = {
    currentPassword: Joi.string().required().label("Password"),
    newPassword: Joi.string().min(12).max(64).required().label("Password"),
    newPasswordRepeated: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref("newPassword")).required(),
  };

  validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.account, this.schema, options);
    if (!error) return null;
    const errors = {};
    for (let item of error.details) {
      errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    }
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    console.log(obj);
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    console.log(schema);
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;
    //todo : call server
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];
    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({
      account: account,
      errors: errors,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { errors, account } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="col-md-5 offset-md-3">
          <form
            className="login-form"
            onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}
          >
            <p />
            <p className="form-label">Current password</p>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="currentPassword"
              name="currentPassword"
              value={account.currentPassword}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {errors.currentPassword && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger">{errors.currentPassword}</div>
            )}
            <p className="form-label">New password</p>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="newPassword"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={account.newPassword}
            />
            {errors.newPassword && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger">{errors.newPassword}</div>
            )}
            <p className="form-label">Confirm password</p>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="newPasswordRepeated"
              value={account.newPasswordRepeated}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {errors.newPasswordRepeated && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger">
                {errors.newPasswordRepeated}
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="submit-login-form">
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Submit"
                disabled={this.validate()}
              ></input>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChangePassword;
```

When the user enters a repeated password, I want to validate whether that repeated password matches the new password already entered. This is done within the `validateProperty` method.The problem is that Joi **returns validation error even if both passwords match**. I appreciate any help with this. [image]

Answer (score 2):

After some researching, I was able to figure out what was the problem.
The problem lies in method `validateProperty` specifically in Joi schema used when validating the field `newPasswordRepeated`. In this schema, it is necessary to add a validation rule for `newPassword`. Therefore I changed my `validateProperty` method like below:

```
validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    if (name === "newPasswordRepeated") {
      const { account } = this.state;
      const obj = { newPassword: account.newPassword, [name]: value };
      const schema = {
        [name]: this.schema[name],
        newPassword: this.schema["newPassword"],
      };
      const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
      return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
    } else {
      const obj = { [name]: value };
      const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
      const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
      return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
    }
  };
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just write your password and password confirmation like this:

```
password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required(),
password_confirmation: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().options({ language: { any: { allowOnly: 'must match password' } } })
```